# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type int and string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, crud

```
public void Delete()
{
    try
    {
        string m = Request.QueryString["m"];
        Chef tbl = db.chefs.SingleorDefault(x => x.ChefId == m);
    }
    catch()
    { }
}
```

Doing CRUD operation using Entity Framework in which main table has 4 columns `chefId`, `Name`, `Salary` and `phone`. When I tried to perform a delete operation through main `ID`, I get this error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type int and string

Comment: What is the data type of ChefId in the model for chefs?

Comment: @ShubhamYadav: If `m` has `string` type and `ChecfId` is `int` then why you are trying to compare these?

Answer (score 3):

At least it's necessary convert `string` to `int` before to use it:

```cs
public void Delete()
{
    try
    {
        string m = Request.QueryString["m"];
        if (int.TryParse(m, out int id))
        {
            Chef tbl = db.chefs.SingleorDefault(x => x.ChefId == id);
            ....
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: Processing when the `m` value is incorrect 
        }
    }
    catch()
    { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you wholeheartedly for taking out time for us. and answered so quickly